# How to add linkbutton control to table cell dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to add linkbutton control to table cell dynamically and its event handler .?

```
Class SurroundingClass
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim tbl As HtmlTable = New HtmlTable()
        Dim tr As HtmlTableRow = New HtmlTableRow()
        Dim td As HtmlTableCell = New HtmlTableCell()
        tr.Cells.Add(td)
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr)
        Dim lbtn As LinkButton = New LinkButton()
        lbtn.Text = "My Link Button"
        lbtn.Click += New EventHandler(AddressOf LinkButton1_Click) '<- THIS LINE ERROR
        td.Controls.Add(lbtn)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[ERROR message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2x57.jpg)

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I think you have to add the control before you attach the event handler, just move the `td.Controls.Add(lbtn)` up one line.

Comment: Hi @willman, it still same error.  i attach an image (the error message).

Comment: try moving your code to the `Page_Init` instead of `Page_load`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you are using the C# format for attaching the event `"+="`, in VB use the `AddHandler` method.
For Example:
`AddHandler lbtn.Click, AddressOf LinkButton1_Click`

Comment: ah, yes ! no error. But this button function not working  ->  Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

Comment: I think you still need to bind that handler in the `Page_Init` rather than `Page_Load` as ViewState and event dispatching has already occurred by the time the `Page_Load` is called.

Comment: If this answer helped, please be sure to [mark it as such](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)